# Cannot run Python script in Power BI on dataset imported from Azure Blob

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, azure-blob-storage

I imported a large dataset into Power BI from Azure Blob Container and now trying to run some custom Python plotting scripts, however the script runs consistently fail. I get the error below, it cites the DataSource, so I think the error could be coming from it. I have tried to run Python: created some dummy data and ran some transforms on it and it works perfectly. Has anyone encountered such error before, how can I fix this? I cannot install Anaconda, because I am using this for work in a large company and there is no budget allocated to Anaconda licenses.

P.S. Privacy level is set to Public everywhere.

P.P.S. The Python PATH looks correct.

```
    DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: A problem occurred while processing your Python script. 
Here are the technical details: [Expression.Error] We couldn't parse the input provided as a Time value.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=A problem occurred while processing your Python script. 
Here are the technical details: [Expression.Error] We couldn't parse the input provided as a Time value.
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    ExceptionType=Microsoft.PowerBI.Scripting.Python.Exceptions.PythonUnexpectedException
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwEqa.png]

Comment: It can't convert a value into a time datatype. I would check your datatypes/transformations. If you doing plotting which is a later stage, would it be best to import it using Power Query then do data transformations??

Comment: Run your Python import script in an IDE debugger and check why the datetime conversion fails. This has nothing to do with not using Anaconda.

Comment: it seems that Power BI does not properly parse the data types, e.g. because of different decimal separator. I was able to fix this by manually binding datatypes to text.

Answer (score 0):

The error has to do with errors Power BI is making while parsing the data. The safest bet is to bind the datatypes of all the columns that contain NaN values in original data to text in Power Query (also possible in GUI). I wonder if there is a way to do deal with NaN values automatically.